# Ribbon and List Item Buttons

Tags: sharepoint-online, ribbon, button

I have a couple of questions related to buttons in the list items:

1. How can I, using JavaScript, change name of default ribbon button "Save" to "Submit" on New List Item form? I managed to change the bottom button using web parts and the below code, but need to do the same for the ribbon section:

   ```
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("changeSaveBtnTxt()");  
   function changeSaveBtnTxt()  
    {  
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");  
    for(i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++)  
    {  
    if(inputs[i].type == "button" && inputs[i].value == "Save")  
    {  
    inputs[i].value = "Submit";  
    }  
    }  
    }
   ```
2. Each list item allows adding attachments and editing them within the list item. Attachments can have different formats (word, excel), are included in the list item in form of the link and can be edited online. If you click on attachment link, it opens in the same browser window.

   - How can I add a custom "Go Back" button on the screen with the opened attachment that goes back to the current list item and not to the list view? I need to have this when I finish editing attachment online and click "Share" and when I simply want to preview it and go back. I only see a link to the main list view.
3. How can I add "Save Draft" button on both list item ribbon and at the bottom of the list item, which allows me to store completed / partially completed list item without triggering a workflow? I would like it to work in such way, that once "Save Draft" is clicked, it saves an updated form in the list and attaches a "Draft" flag next to the item in the main list view (no workflow is triggered then) and once someone edits such "Draft" item and clicks "Submit", "Draft" flag disappears and workflow is triggered.

I'd appreciate your help.
Thanks!
Natalia